# How to reload when a route parameter changes with Meteor FlowRouter?

Tags: meteor, routes, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I am using Meteor and FlowRouter, and I would like to force my page to reload when I change the url (or alternatively one of the parameters of my route). Would anyone know a way to do so?

There has been a few [debates](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout/issues/21) over this, but I haven't found a satisfactory answer yet.

**PS:** 
I know one suggested method is to put `FlowRouter.watchPathChange()` inside a `Tracker.autorun()` but this doesn't seem very satisfactory for what I want to do (changing css classes based on the route parameter), plus I'd like to have the effect of having a page reload.

Answer (score 1):

> FlowRouter has a few reactive APIs for accessing the URL state very efficiently:
>
> - FlowRouter.getParam("paramName")
> - FlowRouter.getQueryParam("queryParamName")
> - FlowRouter.getRouteName()

[FlowRouter guide](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/accessing-the-url-state)

Putting `FlowRouter.watchPathChange()` inside a `Tracker.autorun()` is not the only option. You can put in autorun some of functions listed above.